# jquery toggle with different buttons

Tags: jquery

The "button" toggles a full screen Overlay. I don't want the button to close the Overlay when it's opened. Instead the whole Overlay should be the button to toggle the Overlay itself off (so the viewer can click anywhere to turn it off.)

Can someone help me :)? I'm new to jquery so excuse me if it is a stupid/simple question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("overlay").toggle();
  });
});
```

Thank you in advance and greetings.

Comment: `toggle` means show and hide, if you want only to show only your div then use `show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `show()` to show the `overlay` on `button` click and `hide()` to hide the `overlay` on overlay click...

Also `overlay` should be a `class` or `id` something...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#overlay").show();
  });
  $("#overlay").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```